# oracle sql ordering results

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the bellow oracle query:

```
SELECT
    table_to_check.managed_system_serial,
    CASE
        WHEN infraprod.aix_servers.managed_system_serial IS NULL THEN
            'NO'
        ELSE
            'YES'
    END serial_exists,
    name
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            column_value managed_system_serial
        FROM
            TABLE ( sys.odcivarchar2list('BW020', 'D761P', '22DFW', 'BW020') )
    ) table_to_check
    LEFT JOIN infraprod.aix_servers ON table_to_check.managed_system_serial = infraprod.aix_servers.managed_system_serial
```

The result from running the above is:

[image]

I am trying to make the MANAGED_SYSTEM_SERIAL column appear in sequence as the serials are already in the list. What I want to achieve is this:

```
MANAGED_SYSTEM_SERIAL  NAME     SERIAL_EXISTS
BW020                                NO
D761P                 gmp3dr         YES
22DFW                 PROM1VIOS2     YES
22DFW                 PROM1VIOS1     YES
22DFW                 promdb1        YES
BW020                                NO
```

*The serials above are just a sample. The real number is around 1000 in total.

**There might be multiple entries per serial but this is not a problem, I just need to get them to appear in the results ordered as they are here in this list:

```
(
    'BW020',
    'D761P',
    '22DFW',
    'BW020'
)
```

As my knowledge in SQL is almost zero this has troubled me for a week and I can't find a solution that fits.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Documentation is a good way to start learning: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/cncpt/sql.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `rownum` in inner query and use it to sort output:

```
select t.managed_system_serial, name, 
        case when a.managed_system_serial is null then 'NO' else 'YES' end SERIAL_EXISTS
  from (
    select rownum rn, column_value managed_system_serial 
      from table(sys.odcivarchar2list('BW020', 'D761P', '22DFW', 'BW020'))) t
  left join aix_servers a on a.managed_system_serial = t.managed_system_serial
  order by t.rn
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=db2c9d434733046239610d696a5e2c65)</sup>**

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just looking for `order by`?

```
order by MANAGED_SYSTEM_SERIAL
```